# PHP Criar array dinâmico a partir de um SQL e Separar por uma quantidade de registro especificado em outro Array

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Galera

Sou Novo em PHP e minha Logica esta Ruim D+

Preciso selecionar(SQL) uma lista de Ofertas e separar as Ofertas de 6 em 6  e a a parti dai criar os array contendo as 6 Ids das Ofertas.

**Código:**

```
// SELECT DE FORMA RANDOMICA
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Oferta  ORDER BY RAND()";

//Seleciono todos as Ofertas
$totalOfertas = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Conta o resultado do select  
$contaTotalOfertas = mysqli_num_rows($totalOfertas);

//defino a quantidade de registro por pagina
$quantidadePorPagina = 6;

// calcular o numero de pagina necessárias para apresentar as ofertas
$numeroPagina = ceil($contaTotalOfertas/$quantidadePorPagina);  

// Este Primeiro  Array traz a pagina 

for($i = 1; $i < $numeroPagina + 1; $i++){ 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalOfertas)) {

        /* Aqui preciso armazenar os Ids das ofertas por paginas 
         * tipo Criar Dinamicamente os Array das paginas e armazenar as 6 Ofertas 
         */ em arrays.
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer um array de arrays, sendo que cada sub array contém 6 ids (ou menos caso tenha acabado)?

Comment: Sim é isso tenho que montar um Slider na pagina principal que tenha
6 registro no primeiro slider e assim suscetivamente nos proximos 

Então faço um select de forma randômica e  quebro a seleção em 6 
para montar  o slider

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um array bidimensional, mais conhecida como matriz. Por exemplo, a posição [0] [0] será o primeiro ID dos primeiros 6 produtos, a posição [0] [1] será o segundo ID. Assim vai até que fiquem todos completos.

**Tente desta maneira:**

```
for($i = 1; $i < $numeroPagina + 1; $i++){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalOfertas)){
        for($j = 0; $j <= $quantidade_de_produtos / 6; $j++){ // Aqui está dividido por 6 porque você vai dividir o array de 6 em 6
            for($k = 0; $k < 6; $k++){
                $matriz_de_ids[$j][$k] = $row['oferta_id'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Agora apenas adapte o seu código de acordo com as variáveis acima.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazendo desta maneira com a logica postada adicionei a função array_chunk

O Erro estava em utilizar o While com o for estava repetindo tudo

```
 for($j = 1; $j <= $contaTotalOfertas; $j++){ 
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalOfertas);  

      $y = $j-1;
      $linha[$y] = $row["idOferta"];   

}

print_r(array_chunk($linha,6));
```

Answer (score 1):

De forma simples, com um único loop, mas é necessário duas variáveis para guardar os índices, uma é incrementada sempre a cada iteração, a outra é incrementada de 6 em 6 iterações usando o operador módulo (`%`):

```
$organized = [];

$data = [
["id" => 0],
["id" => 1],
["id" => 2],
["id" => 3],
["id" => 4],
["id" => 5],
["id" => 6],
["id" => 7],
["id" => 8]
];

$index = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    if ($i % 6 == 0) $index++;

    $organized[$index][] = $data[$i];
}

echo var_dump($organized);
```

No seu caso `$data` seria o resultado do SQL

Answer (score 0):

Primeira etapa concluída  o código ficou enxuto 
Agora é montar o Html.

```
 // SELECT
    $sql = "SELECT idOferta, NomeOferta  FROM Oferta ORDER BY RAND() ";
    //Seleciono todos os Produtos   
    $totalOfertas = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // Conta o resultado do select  
    $contaTotalOfertas = mysqli_num_rows($totalOfertas);
    //defino a quantidade de registro por pagina
    $qdtOfertasPorPagina = 6;

    //Crio o Array de um SELECT 
    for ($ofertas = array (); $row = $totalOfertas->fetch_assoc(); $ofertas[] = $row);
    // Divido pelo numero de Paginas 
    $paginas_Oferta  = array_chunk($ofertas, $qdtOfertasPorPagina);

    print_r($paginas_Oferta);
```